# How to load multiple PDF documents with PDFJS/pdfjsLib's SimpleViewer

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I am using the official [SimpleViewer component example](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/components) from [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), which works fine for a single document with several pages, until I try to load multiple documents, which does not work as expected.

The first document loads correctly, the second document just displays loading indicators, and no errors.

I have re-created the code on a JsFiddle in a class, so hopefully someone can help me understand where this is going wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/redfox05/xvpzwLc2

The original examples are found here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/components

### The problem

Single document will load, multiple documents will not. Just shows loading indicators. No errors in console.

### The code:

```js
class MyPDFViewer {
    constructor( options ) {
        this.pdf_count = 0;
        return this.initPDFViewer( options.urls, options.target );
    }

    initPDFViewer( url_array, target ) {

        if( !Array.isArray( url_array )) {
            url_array = [ url_array ];
        }

        var new_url_array = [ url_array[0], url_array[0] ];
        this.loadMultiplePDF( new_url_array, target );
    }

    loadMultiplePDF( url_array, target ) {
        // Load first PDF via initPDFViewer, and loads the rest in callbacks.
        if( Array.isArray( url_array ) && url_array.length > 0 ) {
            var current_url = url_array.pop();

            // Start to cycle through each pdf, loading the first one
            var container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            container.className = 'pdfContainer';
            container.setAttribute('data-document-index', this.pdf_count);
            target.appendChild( container );

            var load_result = this.loadPDF( current_url, container, this.pdf_count );
            load_result.then(() => {
                this.loadMultiplePDF( url_array, target );
            });
            this.pdf_count++;
        }
    }

    loadPDF( pdf_url, container, pdf_id ) {
        var $this = this;

        // Code based on pdfJS examples/components/simpleviewer.js

        // customizable options for PDF loading
        var pdf_link_target = pdfjsLib.LinkTarget.BLANK;
        var search_param = ''; // optional. For highlighting any search params in the pdf.

        // Insert loading text. Must be inserted OUTSIDE of the pdf container to prevent conflict with pdf viewer, as the pdf viewer seems to get loaded into whatever is inside the container.
        $( container ).before( $( '<span type="text" class="pdf-loading t-text" id="pdf-loading-'+ pdf_id +'"></span>' ).text( 'Loading...' ) );

        var pdf_viewer = document.createElement( 'div' );
        pdf_viewer.setAttribute('data-pdf-id', pdf_id );
        // pdf_viewer.setAttribute('id', 'viewer' );
        pdf_viewer.className = 'pdfViewer';
        container.appendChild( pdf_viewer );

        if (!pdfjsLib || !pdfjsLib.getDocument || !pdfjsViewer || !pdfjsViewer.PDFViewer) {
            console.error("pdfjs-dist library is not properly set-up.");
            return false;
        }

        // The workerSrc property shall be specified.
        // pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "dist/pdf.worker.bundle.js";
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mozilla/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js';
        
    // Some PDFs need external cmaps.
        var CMAP_URL = "framework/pdfjs-cmaps/";
        var CMAP_PACKED = true;

        // var DEFAULT_URL = "../../web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf";
        var DEFAULT_URL = pdf_url;
        var SEARCH_FOR = search_param; // try 'Mozilla';

        // Can comment this out, as it's already defined above.
        // var container = document.getElementById( pdfCanvasID );

        var eventBus = new pdfjsViewer.EventBus();

        // (Optionally) enable hyperlinks within PDF files.
        var pdfLinkService = new pdfjsViewer.PDFLinkService({
            eventBus: eventBus,
            externalLinkTarget: pdf_link_target
        });

        // (Optionally) enable find controller.
        var pdfFindController = new pdfjsViewer.PDFFindController({
            eventBus: eventBus,
            linkService: pdfLinkService,
        });

        var pdfViewer = new pdfjsViewer.PDFViewer({
            container: container,
            eventBus: eventBus,
            linkService: pdfLinkService,
            findController: pdfFindController,
        });
        pdfLinkService.setViewer(pdfViewer);

        eventBus.on("pagesinit", function () {
            // We can use pdfViewer now, e.g. let's change default scale.
            pdfViewer.currentScaleValue = "page-width";

            // We can try searching for things.
            if (SEARCH_FOR) {
                pdfFindController.executeCommand("find", { query: SEARCH_FOR });
            }
        });

        // Loading document.
        var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({
            url: DEFAULT_URL,
            cMapUrl: CMAP_URL,
            cMapPacked: CMAP_PACKED,
        });
        return loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdfDocument) {
            // Document loaded, specifying document for the viewer and
            // the (optional) linkService.
            pdfViewer.setDocument(pdfDocument);

            pdfLinkService.setDocument(pdfDocument, null);

            // Remove loading text
            $( '#pdf-loading-'+ pdf_id ).remove();
        });

    }
}

var urls = ['https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf'];
var pdf_target = document.getElementById('the-container');

var PDFResume = new MyPDFViewer({
                    urls: urls,
                    target: pdf_target
                });
```

```html
<!-- This is the version based on simpleviewer -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mozilla/pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer.css" />
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mozilla/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mozilla/pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer.js"></script>

<h1>PDF.js SimpleViewer example</h1>


<div id="the-container"></div>
```